# Create slots object instance performance

Tags: python, performance, python-internals, slots

I have a piece of code that generates an instance of an object using a list of values. For example:

Given a simple class implementing `__slots__`

```
class A(object):
  __slots__ = ('a', 'b')
```

and a list of values

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
```

we create a new instance of the object via

```
>>> o = A.__new__(A)
>>> o
<__main__.A object at 0x0617AE70>
```

we then fill in the attributes of the object using the elements in the list

```
>>> for idx, element in enumerate(l):
...   setattr(o, o.__slots__[idx], element)
>>> o.a
1
>>> o.b
2
```

I'm performing this in a loop over many lists of values, and after profiling my program this is where it spends a lot of it's time. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this that's faster using plain python (no pypy or cython).

Notes:

- My program actually calls `cls.__new__(cls)` from a method that's inherited by my `__slots__` object. Since I don't know the class that's calling the method, this was the only way I found to create the new instance of that particular class type.
- I'm creating these objects from a file containing values, but this is a requirement of the program.

Comment: what is the purpose of the program? I'm sorry, but since I have no idea what it does, the code is rather ... difficult to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Probably won't get you more performance - but it would be more beautiful ("Pythonic") to do: `for  attr, element in zip(o.__slots__, l): setattr(o, attr, l)`

Comment: My guess is that your problem is too specific.  I think it requires a lot more context (probably too much for SO?) to give you a good answer.

Comment: @jsbueno I do like your "Pythonic" method as it is easier to read, but the performance is a bit worse (roughly 5% from a quick benchmark).

Comment: Why you need an object (instance of `A`) at first place? Python can do heavy processing with plain data structures. And "oop" way often is a source of unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 2):

So, I can have some ideas there, but they'd be more or less speculative.
One idea is to use named tuples, instead of direct object attributes.

The downside is that, unless your classes themselves inherit from namedtuples (and there would be some hacking needed), you will have an extra component in the path to the attributes.

But them, something along:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class MyClass42(object):
    __slots__ = ["attrs"]
    scheme = namedtuple("attrs", "attr1 attr2 attr3 attr4")

    def __init__(self, attrs):
        self.attrs = self.scheme(*attrs)

# and to create the classes:
o = cls(attrs)

# the downsides are that you have to access attributes like

o.attrs.attr1
# and all such attributes are imutable :-/
```

Note that you can just use the "cls" var as a callable to build
an instance in Python - unlike some languages 
 in which you need the literal class name. 
 no need to call `cls.__new__` and populate the attributes
"manually". This will move

(on a side note, avoiding 1 letter variable names improves readability a lot,
but if you prefer to do so, you should really  avoid the name `'l'` as it just looks like `'1'` - I've used `'attrs'` above)

Comment: I'll try and give this a shot today and report back. For the ``l`` name issue, I actually use more descriptive names, however I slimmed them for demo usage in my question; good call on that either way.

Answer (score 1):

Another try would be to assign the values as a list to the objects, and handle access to them lazily in a `__getattribute__` methods. While this will almost certainly spare you time in object creation, it will transfer that time to first attribute usage (but them, I don't know if you really have to access all attributes on all objects - you could fine tune your strategy) - and you will have a huge impact in memory usage, if that is an issue.

```
class MyClass42(object):
    __slots__ = ["raw_attrs", "attr1", "attr2", ...]


    def __init__(self, attrs):
        self.raw_attrs = attrs

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        attr = self.raw_attrs[self.__slots__.index(attr_name) - 1]
        setattr(self, attr_name, attr)
        return attr
```